# a cube is a source for another cube

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, cube

i have a similar case like the following example and i need somebody to suggest a good practice in such case.

say that you have two cubes, the first one is a timesheet cube, where you can find how many hours an employee worked on a project in a specific date. an employee can work on many projects in a day and many employees can work on one project. some employees do not work on projects, such as the employees under the supporting departments (like accounting, ISD, HR ...etc) they write there hours on *let's say* "general".
The second cube is project_funder, that shows how much money a funder put in a project. a project can be funded by many funders, and a funder can provide many projects.

how can i bring the relation between the project and the funder from the second cube and use it in the first cube (timesheet cube), to find something like: employee emp1 worked 8 hours on project proj1 which was funded by funder1 and funder2 ? ... i'm using SSAS 2008

Answer (score 2):

It's not known for having good perfomance on large datasets, but have you read up on LOOKUPCUBE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144720.aspx

```
Returns the value of a Multidimensional Expressions (MDX) expression 
evaluated over another specified cube in the same database.
```

Here's a nice example:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Lookup Internet Order Count] AS    
LOOKUPCUBE("Mined Customers", "([Measures].[Internet Order Count], 
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[" + 
[Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.Name + "])")

SELECT [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON COLUMNS,    
{
 [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], 
 [Measures].[Lookup Internet Order Count]
} ON ROWS    
FROM [ADVENTURE WORKS]
```

Taken from: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/814/lookupcube-function-mdx-query-performance-test